# infer a common supertype based on a parameter value and function parameter types

Tags: scala, scala-2.8, type-inference

Should the following be compiled without needing an explicit type definition on `this`?

```
def prepList[B >: A](prefix: PlayList[B]) : PlayList[B] =
  prefix.foldr(this: PlayList[B])((node, suffix) => suffix.prepNode(node))
```

It seems to me that the type should be able to inferred. Is this just a limitation in the Scala compiler, or is there a type-theoretic reason that this cannot be done? I don't really have a feel yet for what the Scala type inferencer can be expected to handle.

Working through that method:

- `B >: A` by definition
- `this` has type `PlayList[A]`, which is a subtype of `PlayList[B]` since `B >: A` and PlayList is covariant in `A`.
- `node` has type `B`, the parameter type of `prefix`.
- second parameter to function parameter `f` in `foldr` has the same type (declared `B`) as the first parameter to `foldr`.
- Thus `suffix` has the same type as `this`, so in particular it is a `PlayList[A]`. Since `B >: A`, `suffix.prepNode()` takes a `B`.

I would like the compiler to see that `suffix.prepNode(node)` is legal where `node` has type `B`. It appears to be able to do this only if I explicitly specify a type on the invocation of `foldr` or on the reference to `this` in that invocation.

Interestingly, if I specify explicit types on the function parameters as `(node: B, suffix: PlayList[B])`, a type mismatch error is still generated on the parameter to the method call `suffix.prepNode(node)`: `"found: B, required: A"`

I'm using Scala 2.8 RC6. Full example below, the line in question is line 8.

```
sealed abstract class PlayList[+A] {
  import PlayList._
  def foldr[B](b: B)(f: (A, B) => B): B

  def prepNode[B >: A](b: B): PlayList[B] = nel(b, this)
  def prepList[B >: A](prefix: PlayList[B]): PlayList[B] =
    // need to specify type here explicitly
    prefix.foldr(this: PlayList[B])((node, suffix) => suffix.prepNode(node))

  override def toString = foldr("")((node, string) => node + "::" + string)
}

object PlayList {
  def nil[A]: PlayList[A] = Nil
  def nel[A](head: A, tail: PlayList[A]): PlayList[A] = Nel(head, tail)
  def nel[A](as: A*): PlayList[A] = as.foldRight(nil[A])((a, l) => l.prepNode(a))
}

case object Nil extends PlayList[Nothing] {
  def foldr[B](b: B)(f: (Nothing, B) => B) = b
}
case class Nel[+A](head: A, tail: PlayList[A]) extends PlayList[A] {
  def foldr[B](b: B)(f: (A, B) => B) = f(head, tail.foldr(b)(f))
}
```

---

**EDIT:** second attempt to reason through the compilation steps

- Renaming for clarity, `foldr` takes parameters of types `(T)((U, T) => T)`. We're trying to infer the values of types `U` and `T`.
- There is a relationship between the first parameter to `foldr` and the second parameter to the function - they're the same thing, `T`. (In partial answer to Daniel.)
- The types of the objects we're passing as those parameters are `this: PlayList[A]` and `suffix: PlayList[B]`
- So, since `B >: A`, the most specific common super type is `PlayList[B]`; therefore we have `T == PlayList[B]`. **Note** that we don't need any relationship between `U` and `T` to deduce this.

This is where I get stuck:

- From the compile error message, the inferencer clearly thinks that `node` has type `B` (that is, `U == B`).
- I can't see how it gets to the conclusion that `U == B` without inferring it from the type parameter of `suffix`. (Can the scala compiler do this?)
- If that step of inference is what happens, then it follows that `U == B`, and we've compiled successfully. So which step went wrong?

---

**EDIT 2:** In renaming the `foldr` parameter types above I missed that `U == A` by definition, it's the type parameter of the `PlayList` class. I think this is still consistent with the above steps though, since we're calling it on an instance of `PlayList[B]`.

So at the call site, `T == PlayList[B]` as the least common super-type of a couple of things, and `U == B` by definition of `foldr` on the receiver. That seems concise enough to narrow down to a couple of options:

- the compiler can't resolve those multiple types and compute the upper bound of `B`
- bug in getting from return type `PlayList[B]` of `foldr` to type of parameter of `prepNode` (skeptical)

Answer (score 3):

I'm no type expert but here is what happens when I try to infer.

`((node, suffix) => suffix.prepNode(node))` returns some unknown type `PlayList[T]`, where T extends A . It is passed as an argument to foldr which returns the type of the function that was passed to it (`PlayList[T]` where T extends A). And this is supposed to be of some type `PlayList[B]`.

So my guess is that `this:PlayList[B]` is necessary to indicate that T and B are related.

May be you need to have PlayList be parametric in two types `PlayList[+A, B >: A]` as you have prepNode and propList that seem to work on the same type that extends A?

Said differently, your original class definition could have been defined like this:

```
def prepNode[T >: A](b: T): PlayList[T]
def prepList[U >: A](prefix: PlayList[U]): PlayList[U]
```

But you used B in both cases and the compiler doesn't know that T and U are the same.

---

Edit, you can play around with the -explaintypes option and see what the compiler does depending on type hints you get. Here is the output of explaintypes and removing the `:PlayList[B]` (with 2.8.0.RC1):

```
$ scalac -explaintypes -d classes Infer.scala
found   : node.type (with underlying type B)
 required: A
    prefix.foldr(this)((node, suffix) => suffix.prepNode(node))
                                                         ^
node.type <: A?
  node.type <: Nothing?
    B <: Nothing?
      <notype> <: Nothing?
      false
      Any <: Nothing?
        <notype> <: Nothing?
        false
      false
    false
  false
  B <: A?
    B <: Nothing?
      <notype> <: Nothing?
      false
      Any <: Nothing?
        <notype> <: Nothing?
        false
      false
    false
    Any <: A?
      Any <: Nothing?
        <notype> <: Nothing?
        false
      false
    false
  false
false
```

Hope this helps shed some light. May be a question around when scalac can infer and when it cannot infer would be helpful.

Comment: You're right that I'm looking for the compiler to see that these should be the same, in some sense, for this invocation, but in general T and U are not the same: consider the case where I call these two methods separately. B in that declaration is only the name of the type bound used within that method scope. In this case, my understanding is that PlayList[B] is a common supertype of this and suffix, and should therefore be inferred to be the type of both. That is, the formal type parameter B of prepNode should have the same value in this invocation as the actual type parameter B of prepList.

Comment: Then may be my suggestion is not the right one. Still, it seems that having to specify `this: PlayList[B]` makes sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `foldr` does not specify `B >: A`, so, as far as `foldr` is concerned, there is no relationship between it's own `A` and `B` types. As far as `foldr` is concerned, `suffix` and `node` are completely unrelated -- even though you happen to have passed related parameters to it.

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. In general we don't want that constraint on the declaration of foldr (certainly there are other valid uses where B has no relation to A) and I don't see that we need it in this case to resolve the types. I've updated the question with an attempt to reason this through...